# Setting root page to activeAdmin default login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Im having dificulty in setting the root page in may Rails app to the default login page of the Active Admin gems, at localhost:3000/admin/login. Here's my routes.rb:

```
TestActiveadmin::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
  match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  resources :sessions
  resources :users

end
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Tell rails you want the default root to go to the admin namespace, dashboard controller, index action:

```
root to: "admin/dashboard#index"
```

Comment: make sure that 
root to: 'admin/dashboard#index'
is above
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

Answer (score 20):

You can edit the Active Admin config file: `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
config.root_to = 'admin/dashboard#index'
```