# Remove dashboard page from ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to replace the default dashboard page in ActiveAdmin with a custom page.

This is mainly because I want a page based on a resource, i.e. a page generated with `ActiveAdmin.register` and not with `ActiveAdmin.register_page`.

I just deleted the `dashboard.rb` file, hoping that `MyCustomAdmin` that is a regular (and working) ActiveAdmin resource, would simply take the place of dashboard.

But it didn't, instead I'm getting this error:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController
```

So I changed the ActiveAdmin initializer and set:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb

config.root_to = 'my_custom_admin#index'
```

I also have `MyCustomAdmin` like this:

```
# app/admin/my_custom_admin.rb

ActiveAdmin.register MyCustomAdmin do
  menu :priority => 1, :label => 'Report'

  index do
    column "column 1 title", :column1
  end

end
```

Among my models I also have:

```
# app/models/my_custom_admin.rb

class MyCustomAdmin < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So the problem is when I try to access on `localhost:3000/admin` I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::MyCustomAdminController
```

But if I go to `localhost:3000/admin/my_custom_admin` it works just fine.

Why is `localhost:3000/admin` not working?

Comment: Check out the 2nd answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087362/setting-root-page-to-activeadmin-default-login-page -- change to the controller/action you want to use.

Comment: not a great luck yet :-(. the idea of modyfing the config/initializer/active_admin.rb seems the way to go, but if i set config.root_to = 'my_admin_class#index' i get an 'uninitialized constant'; if i put (as suggested) admin/my_admin_class#index i get and 'unizialized constant Admin::Admin'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Active admin generates a controller for you. And the controller is pluralized.

So, in the active admin initializer you should use plural form:

```
config.root_to = 'my_custom_admins#index'
```

And this is the solution.

It complains that

```
uninitialized constant Admin::MyCustomAdminController
```

because what it has initialized is:

```
MyCustomAdminsController
```

instead.

Answer (score 12):

In **app/admin/dashboard.rb**

set menu false to hide the dashboard button.

In **config/initializers/active_admin.rb**

set something like this:

config.root_to = 'entities#index'

Answer (score 1):

Using ActiveAdmin 0.5.0 I was able to:

1) make a page other than the dashboard the default ActiveAdmin page.

2) remove the dashboard tab from the menu. (still accessible via url)

Additions to config/initializers/active_admin.rb :

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
...
  # The default start page becomes SomethingElse
  config.root_to = 'something_else#index'
end

module ActiveAdmin
  module Dashboards
    class << self
      # Remove the dashboard tab from the menu
      alias_method :original_add_to_menu, :add_to_menu
      def add_to_menu(namespace, menu)
        # empty
      end
    end
  end
end
```