# undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007f97b41326f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to work on a RoR project that someone else created. I am trying to log in and created a new user name and password for the project. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007f97b41326f0>
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: name_of_app_development
  pool: 5
```

Comment: Paste your routes.rb file here. Especially the root_path route.

Comment: It is very long. I have shown the whole thing here: http://pastie.org/9686239

Comment: I guess, your `RegistrationsController` should use either `authenticated_root_path` or `unauthenticated_root_path` instead of just `root_path` (it probably redirects to it in one or several of its actions). These are the roots that are defined in your `routes.rb` (see the `as:` parts).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have `root` defined within your `routes.rb`, e.g:

```
root 'home#index'
```

Comment: Hmm...I think I do in the unauthenticated section of the pastie shown above (I did not create this file, I am going to try working on it, but am having issues actually signing in and getting it to work)

Answer (score 0):

You are using active admin, seems to have some root problems. Try:

[Setting root page to activeAdmin default login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087362/setting-root-page-to-activeadmin-default-login-page)

```
root to: "admin/dashboard#index"
```

In your routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'controller#action'
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
    authenticated :user do
  ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm...when I sign up I am getting this error: undefined method `action' for ActionController:Module

Comment: That's because you have tell rails which action from what controller would you like to render, like: home#index, users#new or whatever.

Comment: Hmm...do you know what I should do to fix this? Should I post some more code?

Comment: No, think about what you want the user to view when he enters the webpage, and replace it with the action and controller. Example: you have a static_pages#index view. Just do: root to: 'static_pages#index' or whatever you need.

Comment: Ok - but this project should have been set up to work already. I am not sure I get why there are issues like this? Is there an issue with the way my local environment is?

Comment: Push the code to github and ask for help there. Without viewing the full scope I can do nothing else than giving you some advice. If something else is failing is not an stack overflow question.